# Is there a way to get Rust to treat pointers as non-aliasing, so it can mark them as `noalias` for LLVM's optimizer?

Tags: rust, llvm-codegen

The following example of pointer aliasing:

```
pub unsafe fn f(a: *mut i32, b: *mut i32, x: *const i32) {
  *a = *x;
  *b = *x;
}
```

compiles into the following assembly (with `-C opt-level=s`):

```
example::f:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdx]
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdx]
        mov     dword ptr [rsi], eax
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Notice that `x` is being dereferenced twice. LLVM is not treating it as `noalias`. My first thought was to avoid using pointers in the assignments and instead use safe references (since those "[follow LLVM’s scoped `noalias` model](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#behavior-considered-undefined)") to give a hint to the optimizer:

```
pub fn g(a: *mut i32, b: *mut i32, x: *const i32) {
  let safe_a = unsafe { &mut *a };
  let safe_b = unsafe { &mut *b };
  let safe_x = unsafe { &*x };
  *safe_a = *safe_x;
  *safe_b = *safe_x;
}
```

But alas, this produces the exact same result. `safe_x` is still dereferenced twice.

I know this example code is dumb. The parameters could easily be changed to `&i32`/`&mut i32`, or I could just dereference `x` once and store it in a temporary that is used for the assignment. The code here is just meant to be a super simple aliasing test, and I'm interested in the broader picture my question is asking.

Comment: Interestingly, if I use `&mut i32, &mut i32, &i32` as the prototype, the `noalias` attribute is tacked on `x` instead. I seem to remember that `noalias` is not actively passed to LLVM as there are concerns that the `unsafe` semantics need be clarified first, and optimizations applies second, lest LLVM "breaks" the code.

Comment: Maybe relevant: [`Unique<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.Unique.html)

Comment: For the record, I reported the lack of optimization here as [issue #38941](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38941).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Are you perhaps thinking of [issue #31681](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31681)? Indeed, some references aren't marked as `noalias` due to a bug in LLVM (which has recently been fixed), but not all. Some are still able to be marked as `noalias`.

Answer (score 3):

There is, wrap the safe reference in a function or closure:

```
pub unsafe fn f(a: *mut i32, b: *mut i32, x: *const i32) {
    (|safe_a: &mut i32, safe_b: &mut i32, safe_x: &i32| {
        *safe_a = *safe_x;
        *safe_b = *safe_x;
    })(&mut *a, &mut *b, &*x)
}
```

This produces the wanted non-aliasing behavior:

```
example::f:
        movl    (%rdx), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%rdi)
        movl    %eax, (%rsi)
        retq
```

Comment: The function / closure is unnecessary. [All you are doing is converting the raw pointers to references](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=394715120674a36188bd6e8ac7ff0cd8&version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015). This doesn't really show how to treat *pointers* as non-aliasing, just how to convert pointers to references.

Comment: @Shepmaster That's just not true - compare the assembly. In your example `safe_x` is loaded twice - evidence the references are **not** considered non-aliasing. The closure is necessary.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. That seems like a bug (limitation?) By definition, references should not alias. Looking for an issue, I found [the one filed by OP](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38941)!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have made that more explicit in my OP (this is what I meant by "The parameters could easily be changed to `&i32`/`&mut i32`" and what [Matthieu M.'s comment refers to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541835/is-there-a-way-to-get-rust-to-treat-pointers-as-non-aliasing-so-it-can-mark-the#comment70290954_41541835)). Currently `noalias` is only applied to reference function arguments as far as I can tell. I suppose this is a perfectly valid answer to the question, though.